# A series with long-tailed terms

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let's consider the following series:
$$
\zeta = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \xi_k, 
$$
where the sum is understood as the limit in $L_2(\Omega)$, $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$,
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k^2< \infty$, $\xi_k$ are i.i.d. random variables which have a long-tailed distribution (the most interesting case for me is when they have the symmetric Pareto distribution), $E \xi_k=0$, $E \xi_k^2=1$.

1) Is it true (maybe under some extra non-restrictive assumptions) that $\zeta$ has a long-tailed distribution? Heavy-tailed distribution? Is it true that $\zeta$ is absolutely continuous if $\xi_k$ have the symmetric Pareto distribution?

2) Can we prove (maybe under some extra assumptions) an inequality of the following type: 
   $$
   E|\zeta|^s \leq g(E\zeta^2),    
   $$ 
$s>2$, where $g$ is a more or less reasonable function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a comment about absolute continuity: Even in the simplest case $\xi_k$ is Bernoulli $(1/2)$ and $a_k = \lambda^k$ your question is a famous problem about Bernoulli  convolutions. (see https://www.math.washington.edu/~solomyak/PREPRINTS/mandel2.pdf)